# What switch do I need to enable/disable fan with wind speed measurement by a DIY anemometer?

Tags: 12v

I'm going to be making a device for burning man that will effectively evaporate grey water from our camp. This will be mostly wind powered, however when there isn't any wind, I plan on using a high torque, low rpm 12V dc motor to power the device. The power to the motor will be provided by a set of Rynology 100W solar panels which will power up a battery store.

Here is what I would like to do. I want to be able to determine if there isn't any wind in order to engage the power to the motor to take over operations until the wind returns. I plan on achieving this with a DIY Anemometer that is attached to an old CD player motor. When the little CD motor is spun by the wind, the anemometer will produce a little voltage. I would like a switch of some sort that can detect that little voltage, and if its detected, to close the 'gate' that controls the power from the battery store.

It seems I would have 1 lead coming into the switch that will carry the small voltage from the motor, and then two leads one end attached to the battery bank, and the other end attached to the 12V dc motor -- which can be interrupted if there is voltage detected on the aforementioned lead.

Is this a thing? Can I pick this voltage detection gizmo up at a small electronics store? What is this thing called?

EDIT: here are more details of the parts I'm looking at in terms of the motor. This is the motor I will be using to drive the device when there is no wind https://goo.gl/2TWwNS . I haven't decided yet but I'm pretty sure something like this will be used in the aeronmeter https://goo.gl/l8cFUd which seems to be able to produce a little voltage when spun.. here it is in this youtube video... I dont have enough reputation to put more than 2 links in my post. So I left the youtube link in the comment to Transistors suggestion

Comment: An transistor is a popular type of electrical switch.  I might use a relay in this case though, to provide complete electrical isolation.  A relay will connect two leads together when its control voltage is active.  Or, you could maybe use a transmission gate type circuit built with power MOSFETS.  This enters a high impedance state whenever its control voltage is LOW and effectively turns on (to connect the nodes b/w it's input and output) when its control voltage is HIGH.

Comment: Look up 'comparators', they allow you to easily compare two voltages. For switching the motor, look for appropriately rated relays (automotive is a good idea at 12V). Your choice of comparator may not have enough power to drive a large relay, so you will also need something to drive the relay coil. Remember to keep your wind-tester away from the fan.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMLdi4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Anemometer wind detection circuit.*

Assuming your anemometer can put out a few volts the circuit of Figure 1 should work.

- 12 V relay, RLY1, will provide power from the battery to the motor.
- When the anemometer puts out some voltage it will turn on Q1 which will turn on Q2 which will energise the relay.
- When the relay is energised the contact will change over and the motor will be disconnected from the battery.

You need a relay to match the battery voltage. The contacts should be rated >= to your load current. Your local auto shop should have something suitable.

Check the anemometer polarity in the wind before connecting up. Tip: you could test the device and cut-in speed by driving around with the anemometer on the roof of your car.

---

Edit after motor specified:

[image]

[image]

*Figure 2. Motor (generator) specification from [Mabuchi Motor](https://www.neuhold-elektronik.at/datenblatt/N7029.pdf).*

I didn't watch the video but at 3 V it will spin at about 2500 RPM. This means that to generate 3 V you will have to spin it at 2900 RPM. This is close to 50 revs/second and seems most unlikely for an anemometer. If it ever happened then *Burning Man* is over.

You need to come up with a different wind detector.

Comment: Thanks for the schematic, I wish I knew how to actually implement this, and where to get the pieces. You definitely gave a detailed answer more than I expected! I was hoping to find a relay already put together, that I could just tie into the system.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know what voltage your anemometer will give. Find some smart kid to make it up for you. Buy the relay. You've only to find three components which should be in an electronic hobbyist's box of junk.

Comment: How about a schottky, capacitor and resistor on the input? Can we assume it puts out DC? Or is the voltage too low to even overcome 400 mV?

Comment: I've added more details to my answer... the motor used in the aeronmeter can be seen here in this video https://goo.gl/8MTZRf

Comment: Did you notice he's turning the generator with a high speed tool? It's also a different type of motor than yours. See my update.

Comment: I did notice that, and wondered if that had an impact. This is where the idea on the aeronometer came from http://www.instructables.com/id/Easter-Egg-Anemometer-Wind-Speed-Meter/?ALLSTEPS ... it seems to push out a decent amount of dc mA. PS I loved the comment about wind blowing so hard there would be no BM haha. So true

Comment: Notice that the multimeter is set to 0.5 mA. That's a tiny amount of current.

Comment: okay, I guess I need to get a micro generator then? Do they make  these?

Comment: Also something else to note Wind speed seems to vary wildly but I think its safe assume about a ~5 mph wind http://wind.willyweather.com/nv/pershing-county/black-rock-city-burning-man-festival.html

Comment: Could always use a motor that gives out pulses / alternating current (anything from a small stepper motor to a car alternator with W terminal) and work on the frequency rather than voltage output, which will always depend on the load you're put across the motor. Then again, why use a motor when a small magnetic or optical sensor could be used to count revolutions of a turbine with zero loading? Would require a more complex circuit, likely a small micro, but from what I've seen there's a million people doing arduino things at burning man.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a relay like this:

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Crydom/DC60S3/?qs=mNyg5qXQ%2FsdpD8JEee%252brpQ%3D%3D&gclid=CMn1xMnX-M0CFQ-oaQodFeUP-g

You can see in the specs it is good for up to 3A, from ~3-48V.  Also the control input will draw ~2.2 mA to 25 mA.

There are lots of different relays for whatever specific applications you need.

Comment: Thanks for this link. Please forgive my ignorance, as I'm not an electrical engineer ( I write software, so I have a mild understanding of switches, just not the physical kind). Looking at the spec sheet for this switch it seems to do what I need. Would I put the control (the aeronmeter) on 1 and 2, and the motor I want behind the gate on 3 and 4? Sorry if this seems like a dumb question I appreciate the response

Comment: Yep, you would want to connect one of the motor leads to 3, power to 4.  and then the other motor lead to ground.

Comment: 3A seems seriously under-spec'd for a 12V DC motor.

Comment: Yeah, I included the rated amperage so he could decide for himself if this would work for him.  He asked what type of component, not the specific one he should use.  He did not specify how much current this motor takes.

Comment: So I found another motor online that will generate 120V at 1500 RPMS in a 10mph wind, which is doable . https://goo.gl/kFwXI4. The motor that will be engaged if there is no wind that will be powered by the battery bank temporarily until there is wind will be this one https://goo.gl/IosUAi... is there a relay simliar to the one you linked above, that isn't under spec'd and can handle my application? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to solve this mechanically: Rather than an anemometer, just use a flap pointed into the wind (easily done with a weather vane style mount) with a microswitch - when the wind blows, the flap opens and the switch gets pushed (or released).

Mind you, I'd be tempted not to solve this at all and just run the system all the time - because why not? If it's solar powered it's not costing you anything, if the panels are there ready and waiting then why not just leave it running 24/7?

Comment: I definitely considered this, I dont see any harm in just letting it run at all. I can get a PWM and put it in between to help control the speed too. I guess I wanted to try the relay thing because it seemed like a challenge and I wanted to push myself to try something different :D You're absolutely right though, I have the energy coming to and stored already, just use that.

Comment: I guess there's a case for storing energy when not needed and spending it when required at a higher rate than you could otherwise, but the economics of that depend greatly on the likely amounts of available wind, solar, and storage respectively.